# Asset creation in ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts

Is it possible to create assets in ethereum which will automatically get linked with a particular address and will be able to send from one account to another without using a contract? I have seen that there is concept of tokens in ethereum, but what I want is to be able to create multiple assets and settle an exchange between them.

Comment: Yes done many times. You can try it out with the Mist Wallet application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help.But I think smart contract is the only possible way to do this and I have figured out with contract only to create and transfer assets.

Comment: I am struggling with same doubts. Can you plz add more details? The way is to create assets in form of solidity struct/objects and store them in array or something in smart contract where the owner of asset is also recorded and this ownership transfer will be in form of just changing field value which stores owner address and set new owner address. Is this right or you did it in a different way?

Comment: Use the concept of token contracts to implement your assets in ethereum there are number of ERC standard contracts which you can implement just use tokens as assets .

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you can take a look at the Metacoin project and the concept of [colored coins](http://coloredcoins.org/).

> A Meta Coin is a coin that is launched on top of another blockchain, as a “meta” layer. For example a small amount of ether is “marked” and can represent an ounce of gold or a share in a company or even points in a video game. Other words for meta coins that are also used are: Tokens, Cryptoequity, Assets, Crypto Assets, Colored Coins and more.

Comment: Actually bitcoin blockchain has its own api for creating assets and transacting them like in [multichain](http://www.multichain.com/getting-started) but i could not be able to find the same in ethereum

Comment: If you figure out some way to link the `data` field with the Ether being transferred(`value`), you can use the data field to represent a digital asset.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to a new currency over Ethereum? Assets in terms of transactions are bound to their originator (which signs them with a private key using an EC signature); one of the core ideas of the block chain is that each action made by any peers is publicly available and verifiable to others.

If your goal is to create a custom coin over Ethereum have a look at [this](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/12/03/how-to-build-your-own-cryptocurrency/) article.